# Using Express JS to make API external CALL (avoiding cors problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, express

I am trying to make API calls using express js to get some data and then use them for my school project! 
I have heard that I can install an extension or something like that on my browser but that will only work on my pc.

So I am trying to create my own proxy using Express JS. 
Do I need to write something else on I app.get(**'/'**) or is it okay with a slash. 
Thanks in advance!

````
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

let key1 = '8151a53b2c1d4c3db2df'
let url ='http://api.sl.se/api2/realtimedeparturesv4.json?key='+key1+'&siteid=9192&timewindow=5'


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  request( { url: url},
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }
      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
      console.log(body);
    } )
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));```
````

Comment: nothing wrong with doing it, though you might want to add [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) package to handle it for you. and you can do `res.pipe` in place of most of your code.. fyi request package is deprecated

Comment: i am actually new to express js so i was thinking to make it work first like this and than add some middleware to my code! feel free to suggest your idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package like this

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

if you want to enable it for a single route :

```
app.get('/', cors(), (req, res) => { 

});
```